# Context menu binding never gets executed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, contextmenu

I have ListView control in my view with it's own viewmodel A. I have made a seperate UserControl to use as ListViewItem, because it's styling takes a lot of space. In this ListViewItem I have a button, which is binded to viewmodel A and it works fine.

As the context menu has it's own visual tree and cannot bind via ancestor, I have used [binding proxy](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/), to solve this issue. I have tweaked it a little so it worked for my particular case, because if it just used {Binding} it would bind to item's model, not listview's viewmodel.

```
<helpers:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}"/>
```

To check if the binding is correct I've used a converter as a way just to have a breakpoint to check source. Everything was good and I was getting my viewmodel right there.

Now, when I try to bind to this in my context menu

```
<UserControl.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="Open"
                  Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenChatCommand, Source={StaticResource proxy}, Converter={StaticResource DataBindingDebugConverter}}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
   </ContextMenu>
</UserControl.ContextMenu>
```

The command never gets called. I added converter to see if something is wrong, but it turns out, I never get to my converter, which in turn means this code never gets executed.

Anyone with any ideas why this is happening and how to solve this is welcome.

*I think it's the compiler malfunctioning though*

Answer (score 2):

I just did a brief readup on that "binding proxy" you mentioned, but as far as I know, `DataGridTextColumn` is in the same Visual Tree as its `DataGrid`, just that its `DataContext` is bound to its data.

For `ContextMenu`, it's totally different. This one really has a separate tree from its parent. There is no point in using a proxy object in resources, because it is from a different visual tree. When you use `StaticResource`, WPF will search upwards through its visual tree, level by level, inside those elements' `Resource` property (which is a `ResourceDictionary`).

One way is to make that proxy into a singleton, and use `Source={x:Static helpers:BindingProxy.Instance}`. Of course using this means that your proxy can only be used by a single View, or else something unexpected would happen.

The other way is to make use of [`PlacementTarget`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.placementtarget(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the `ContextMenu`.

```
<ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext,
             RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

This is the preferred way, but you need to make sure the parent's `DataContext` is really the VM that you need.

### Edit

There is no super elegant way to do it the MVVM way. The best way is probably through the use of [`Tag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

```
<ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag,
             RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

ListView Control:

```
<MyControl:MyListViewItem .... Tag="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type MyControl:MyListViewView}}}"}" ...>
```

Comment: Now I can bind to the model of ListViewItem, but still not the DataContext of ListView. Still not what I need.

Comment: @Dainius Updated.

Comment: We are getting close! When I click command on my menu item I get this exception:

`"System.InvalidCastException' occurred in GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform.dll
Unable to cast object of type 'MainViewModel' to type 'MatchModel'."`

I used converter to see what value on Command is my MenuItem getting, and it's RelayCommand<MatchModel>, in it's non-public member _execute, properties Target and ActionTarget, lays my VM I'm looking for.

Comment: @Dainius Okay, I'm not a MVVM Light user, so this is definitely out of my normal understanding scope. What is `MatchModel`, and how did it end up inside?

Comment: MatchModel is the actual Model my ListViewItem is binded to. It is contained in my MainViewModel. The ItemSource of my ListView is List<MatchModel>. So far I've got around my problem by just adding ContextMenu in ListView, not in ListViewItem, it's a little spaghetti code now, but at least it works. If you don't know how to solve this nevermind then, you still helped me, I've learned about Tags now!